# Alternative to easy-driver (or adafruit motor shield ) on breadboard

Tags: arduino, motor, driver, stepper-motor, h-bridge

I'm up to implementing bipolar stepper drivers  with STEP  and DIRECTION inputs just as like [easydriver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10267)  and [pololu stepper drivers](http://www.pololu.com/category/120/stepper-motor-drivers) but that on breadboard.Earlier I was using L293D to do that , but it cannot provide phase drive , I researched a bit and found these two instructables which uses L298 (1) and l2619  (2) respectively. However schematics are not very clear and unlikely to those instructable I'll not be using ATtiny2313 , I'll only be using Arduino , as the drivers will have only two inputs (step and dir ), so I believe I can drive four steppers with a single arduino that I can further use with 3D printer.

Is there any other better option for breadboarding a driver with step/dir input ?

(1)-http://www.instructables.com/id/5-stepper-driver/
(2)-http://www.instructables.com/id/45-better-stepper-driver/

Answer (score 5):

The L293D and similar H-bridges are essentially dumb current switching drivers, not stepper controllers: When the ENable pin is high, the A pin input determines whether the corresponding Y pin output is high or low.

In order to implement a 2-input STEP / DIR control, a layer of logic glue is needed, to translate those two control inputs into suitable coil energization signals to be fed into the L293D.

The logic layer needs to not just control a sequence of values for the A pins, but also be aware of stepper position, especially to implement micro-stepping. An application like a CNC is best implemented via micro-stepping, to avoid big jerky steps or a huge gear reduction ratio.

Further, to cope with a variable load on the stepper and yet provide sufficient and consistent step torque, a current-sensing chopper drive is required.

Getting all of those pieces working on a breadboard without using a motor controller or a dedicated microcontroller is a pretty massive task, and would end up costing significantly more than just using a stepper motor controller IC, or at least, as illustrated in one of the instructables mentioned in the question, a dedicated microcontroller.

Finally, depending on the specific stepper motor being used, the current required for driving it will probably far exceed the breadboard's current ratings - A breadboard is not designed to support several amperes of current, even in short bursts. A melted puddle of plastic and metal is a likely outcome.

---

The reason motor controller ICs such as the [A3967](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/A3967.pdf) and the Texas Instruments DRV8825 exist is to simplify stepper motor control, current control / chopping, and microstepping. The two driver modules mentioned in the question use those controllers. Other stepper controller modules, such as the [StepStick](http://reprap.org/wiki/StepStick), exist as well.

These controllers typically cost less than US$4 on eBay ([1](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1PC-A4988-3D-Printer-Driver-Module-Reprap-Prus-StepStick-Stepper-Motor-Driver-/190958749556?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2c76074774)), ([2](http://www.ebay.com/itm/EasyDriver-Shield-Stepping-Stepper-Motor-Driver-Board-V44-A3967-For-Arduino-/181244178570?pt=Home_Automation_Modules&hash=item2a32feb08a)), making it highly unlikely that a breadboard stepper driver could come close in cost or capability.

---

Here is a trivial solution specifically addressing breadboarded stepper controllers:

Obtain a stepper motor controller IC such as the DRV8825, solder it onto a SMD to DIP conversion PCB, plug that PCB into the breadboard, and hook the stepper motor up to this. The support components needed by the motor controller IC can go on the breadboard, other than any parts in a high current path. For those, just hook them up lead to lead, well off the breadboard.

Comment: Then about using a combo of L297-L298 ? That is a step/dir driver two and requuires only two inputs. I checked my local markets , the A49 series driver aren't available , and yes , you are right they cost too much.

Comment: @JatinBatra What part of the world are you in? I find EasyDriver and StepStick boards (without heat-sink) in Mumbai, India for around Rs. 350 to 500 depending on the mood of the seller.

Comment: I am in Delhi , I am not asking about the boards , I was asking about the ICs . I checked out whole Chandni Chowk ( the major electronic market of Delhi )

Comment: Moreover sir , I had some doubts , can you let me know L297 +L298 combo , would that be good . I have pin limitations and want compatiblity with grbl

Comment: @JatinBatra No, you won't find those ICs in retail volumes at Lajpat Rai Market / Bhagirath Palace, simply because they aren't big volume products there. Also, SMD ICs are not sold much in retail in those markets. I would still go with a prebuilt board - I order off eBay.com (**not** ebay.in) often enough - simply because the typical Chinese eBay sellers offer those boards for less than the retail list price of the ICs themselves, including free shipping to India.

Comment: @JatinBatra While kludging together a pair of high and low side drivers such as you suggest could be made to work with a bit of massaging, you miss out on two major advantages of a motor driver IC: current sensing / chopper drive, and high resolution microstepping.

Comment: Gotcha sir ! Since I'm trying this for 3d printer which requires 4 drivers , It will be a kick on my stomach (500 x3 ) , whereas the normal ICs like L293d , here in Lajpat rai cost only 30-40 bucks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering)